# How to fix this ArrayIndex error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I would like to fetch datas with checking id with some numbers.

```
int r = 0;
var ask = from y in entity.sorulars    
          where y.soru_id == questionID[r]
          select new { y.sorutipi_id };

foreach (var hold2 in ask)
{
    questionTypeID[r] = hold2.sorutipi_id;
    r++;
}
```

I use these codes but

> "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ
>   to Entities."

error appears. I guess `questionID[r]` is not supported in `LINQ` so what should I type instead of it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way, declare `var Id=questionID[r];` variable globally and pass the `id` to your query

```
int r = 0;
var Id= questionID[r];

var ask = from y in entity.sorulars    
          where y.soru_id == Id
          select new { y.sorutipi_id };

foreach (var hold2 in ask)
{
    questionTypeID[r] = hold2.sorutipi_id;
    r++;
}
```